# Sending message to selected fb friends by using facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to send message to selected facebook friends by using facebook' javascript sdk. I am using the method below but it only get last id of the array. How should I pass the parameter that will allow to send multiple friends. I want to send message to all friends' ids in the array.

```
      //id of selected friends
      var myFriends=["5029034**","5992788**"];

      FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      to: myFriends,
      name: 'Bind vs Live vs Delegate in Jquery ',
      link: 'http://example.com/2011/05/25/jqueryde-bind-vs-live-vs-delagate/',
      });
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what he was looking for was the `apprequests` method.

[More info](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).